# PHP Session in Kohana 3

Tags: php, session, kohana, kohana-3

So I'm basically unable to use any kind of session in my Kohana 3 project. A few example of the issue :

```
$session = Session::instance();
$session->set('customer_id', $customer->id);
$this->request->redirect('controller/action');
//At the start of the redirected action
$session = Session::instance();
$customer_id = $session->get('customer_id');
```

$customer_id, in the session, has a positive value before the redirect, after it has a value of 0. I also tried with the basic PHP session - which may be disabled in Kohana - I don't know. Didn't thought so, since we can still use $_GET and $_POST.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['customer_id'] = $customer->id;
//At the start of the redirected action
session_start();
$customer_id = $_SESSION['customer_id'];
```

Same scenario as before, except that now the $customer_id, after the redirect, is null.

Not sure what to try right now, I did make sure Sessions were enable in php.ini (I have quite a bunch of others application, under other framework or CMS, currently installed, and I'm convinced at least one of them use sessions). Currently I'm looking into this : http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/3018/using-native-session-array/p1 , though I doubt it's the issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what I was thinking when I was testing this - but I resolved this. I'd have to guess the issue here was my own profound stupidity.

Comment: In the end my code was correct, the error was completely unrelated to the sessions.

Comment: What was your "fix"? Because I think I might be having the same profound brain fart as well. I'm having the same EXACT problem.

Comment: Since the "fix" was never reported: I had the exact same problem today and I fixed it by disabling `session.auto_start` in php.ini. It seems to conflict with Kohana's sessions sometimes.